# What is the SO user deletion rate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

Browsing some of the older SO questions I am noticing quite a few where the original owner of the answer or question is no longer on the site, i.e. have had their accounts deleted. Since deleting an account requires the team to intervene and process the deletion, I am interested in the following:

- How many deletions have there been since launch?
- How many requests are there in a day/week?
- What are the major reasons for these deletions?
- How can this be prevented?

*I don't expect exact numbers, just an indication would be sufficient, the last 2 questions are more valuable to me.*

Comment: Do they have to give a reason?

Comment: They are not required to give a reason as far as I am aware, but I am guessing some do provide one. I know the team will sometimes ask the user if they feel it is a hasty move.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't say what the deletion rate is, but there is [an automated process](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) that deletes old, inactive users:

> We delete cookie-based unregistered accounts when the user has not visited Stack Overflow in four months **AND** the user has less than 100 reputation
>
> We delete OpenID registered accounts when the user has not visited Stack Overflow in four months **AND** the user has only 1 reputation

Comment: deletion rate is about 1000-2000 "users" per week.